# How to apply Collider to Particle and what components are needed for particles?

Tags: unity, particles, monodevelop

**i want to apply collider to particle system** because if i applied the collider to particle ,if any other game object touched to that particle its gives some action or do some operation.so only i need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the particle system component properties you can find a tab that is called collision, then you just tick it and set it to world space, and in order to be detectable you could add a tag to the particle system and make other objects check for the collision with the objects with that tag.

Answer (score 1):

You need to activate the Collision under particle system component itself and set the Collision to be 'World' for particle system component and also check the 'Send Collision Message' check box under Collision. Refer this url

http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/715622/world-particle-system-collider-what-am-i-missing.html